# How can I add hint at the end of EditText?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have view for my recyclerview as shown below:

[image]

And I am aware, that it is not very user friendly. The main goal is that user can fill these boxes with repetitions that they did, but unfortunately I can't do this using simple 5 editboxes, instead I had to add 5 editboxes and 5 textviews inside LinearLayout. Is there any way that I can use only 5 editboxes and the hint "/5" would appear at the end of the each EditText?

Below is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1D1D1B">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#1D1D1B"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exercisesLevelTextView"
                style="@style/fill_box_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:shadowDx="-4"
                android:shadowDy="-4"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/textview"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exercisesNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:shadowDx="-4"
                android:shadowDy="-4"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/textview"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/exercisesLevelTextView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exercisesLevelTextView" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/exercisesCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playVideoButton"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/play_button"
                android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/exercisesCheckBox"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/exercisesCheckBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exercisesCheckBox"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_play"
                tools:ignore="RedundantDescriptionCheck" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/play_button"
                android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playVideoButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/playVideoButton"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/playVideoButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/playVideoButton"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
                app:tint="#FFFFFF"
                tools:ignore="RedundantDescriptionCheck" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exercisesNameTextView">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/series1"
                        style="@style/editBoxExercises2"

                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seriesTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"

                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"
                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:text="@string/_5"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/series2"
                        style="@style/editBoxExercises"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:digits="012345"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"

                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seriesTextView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"
                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:text="@string/_5"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/series3"
                        style="@style/editBoxExercises2"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:digits="012345"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"

                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seriesTextView5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"
                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:text="@string/_5"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/series4"
                        style="@style/editBoxExercises2"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:digits="012345"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"

                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seriesTextView4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"
                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:text="@string/_5"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/series5"
                        style="@style/editBoxExercises2"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:digits="012345"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="1"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"

                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seriesTextView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:shadowDx="-4"
                        android:shadowDy="-4"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:text="@string/_5"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [Material](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields) library actually has a cool framework for it. You can add any text using `suffixText` attribute. Here is an example:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:suffixText="YOUR_STRING_TO_SHOW_AT_THE_END_OF_EDIT_BOX">
    
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Can I make suffix always visible? Because it's only visible only if I click on the edittext

Comment: Good question. AFAIK there is no public API that controls the behaviour of suffix textview. But there may be some possible workarounds for it. Because in the end the suffix text is hold in a `TextView` within the `TexxtInputLayout`. I'll take a look at the API source whether  we can intercept the suffix textview visibility control and let you know of my findings.

Comment: Suffix text is hidden by the framework when the edittext both doesn't have any text input and focus. If it has text in it set by `setText()` method, the suffix will automatically be visible by the framework. But I think this behaviour is not suitable for your case since the edit boxes filled by the user asynchronously, is it?